# Expressions for 'unclear'

Tags: expressions

Basically, I'm looking for something similar to this:

"His reasoning was as clear as dirt."

Are there any other common expressions like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As clear as a black rock at the bottom of a deep well at midnight during a lunar eclipse.

You can make them up as you go along, really, but the most common one I've heard is "clear as mud".

Comment: Ah yes, "clear as mud", not "clear as dirt". Thanks.